# It is possible to use component which is created by decorator "Component" at runtime?

Tags: angular

**I've component's class**

```
class MyComponentLogic {
  log() {
    console.log('logging!');
  }
}
```

**Tying to create component via "Component" decorator**

```
let TestComponent = Component({ template: 'hey', selector: 'app-test' })(MyComponent);
```

**And get error:**

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!
  - JIT compilation is discouraged for production use-cases! Consider AOT mode instead.
  - Did you bootstrap using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server'?
  - Alternatively provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.
```

**If it's not possible can I rewrite template of existing component at runtime**

Comment: How would you like to _"rewrite"_ the template of an existing component? See here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Comment: Adding, removing and editing pipes, directives, components, DOM elements. Class of component creates via script which loads from server

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes you can... but it's not recommended. It would require you to include the Angular Compiler, and you'd be limited to JIT compiilation (in production) - all resulting in somewhat bad performance and a bloated bundle to serve over HTTP.

I think we need more insight into what you're trying to accomplish, to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: I need ability to extend logic of component and override template of existing component. What can u recommend. I will be glad to any answer

Comment: In my case I will load script and execute and the loaded script should create overridden components.

Comment: Have a look at this github repo, to get inspiration on how it could be achieved - https://github.com/LayZeeDK/ivy-dynamic-rendering